# What happens when a thread calls pthread_mutex_unlock on an already unlocked mutex

Tags: c, pthreads

I know this question sounds familiar and it might even be a stupid question but I wasn't able to find the solution to it.

So my question basically is, what happens when a `parent_thread` calls `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)` then calls `pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex)` releasing the mutex, and then `child_thread` calls `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)` followed by `pthread_cond_signal(&condition)` and then `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)`. So this would mean that the mutex is unlocked and now if `parent_thread` attempts to call `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)`, it should result in undefined behavior, right ?

Example code:

```
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void thr_exit() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  done = 1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&c);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}

void *child(void *arg) {
  printf("child\n");
  thr_exit();
  return NULL;
} 
void thr_join() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  while (done == 0)
  pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m); 
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("parent: begin\n"); 
  pthread_t p;
  pthread_create(&p, NULL, child, NULL);
  thr_join();
  printf("parent: end\n"); return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock): _If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results._

Comment: @yano Right, I know that but I found this code from a chapter in a book which indirectly states that this is a good code snippet so I am probably misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, only read your title when I commented.  Just to make sure I understand your order of operations, a long-winded version of the already-posted answer:

parent calls:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m); // locks the mutex
pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);  // releases the mutex
```

child calls:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);  // locks the mutex
pthread_cond_signal(&c); // does nothing to the mutex, it's still locked
// the parent thread has been signaled, but it is still blocked
// because it can't acquire the mutex.
// At this moment in time, the child still owns the mutex, so
// pthread_cond_wait cannot acquire it, thus the parent waits...

pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); // releases the mutex
// ok, the child released the mutex and the parent thread has been signaled.
// The mutex is available. pthread_cond_wait in the parent can
// acquire it and return.
```

parent calls:

```
// now that the mutex is unlocked, the parent can return from its
// pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m) call from above, which returns with the mutex
// locked. A successful call to pthread_cond_wait(..) returns with the
// mutex locked, so this can't successfully return until it acquires the
// mutex.
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);  // releases the locked mutex, no UB
```

Of course, this is only one of several order of operations.  I think your misunderstanding is that `pthread_cond_wait` can't return successfully until it acquires the mutex.  At that point, it correctly calls `pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);` on a locked mutex.

Comment: Right except after child calls ```pthread_cond_signal(&c)``` the ```pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m)``` stops blocking then child calls ```pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)``` releasing the mutex and then parent calls ```pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)```

Comment: @dipps_18 the mutex is locked when the parent calls `_unlock`. Otherwise, it would still be blocked on `_wait`. `_wait` isn't going to immediately return when `_signal` is called, it has to wait for `_signal` and `_unlock`, otherwise it couldn't acquire the mutex and return. This is all dependent on successful operation of course, you'd have to check the return values to be sure.

Comment: I assumed wait immediately returns after signal is called, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

> So this would mean that the mutex is unlocked

No, `pthread_cond_wait` returns with mutex locked.

> if parent_thread attempts to call pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)

Parent just unlocks the mutex after `pthread_cond_wait` returns.

Comment: Right, once ```pthread_cond_signal``` is called the ```pthread_cond_wait``` stops blocking and returnss with mutex locked which was already locked to begin with by child, right ? And then if the child unlocks the mutex, what happens when the parent unlocks the already unlocked mutex after it ?

Comment: `if the child unlocks the mutex` no, `pthread_cond_signal` _waits_ for the signal, then _waits_ for the mutex to be unlocked, i.e. locks the mutex and returns. `pthread_cond_signal` only sends the signal, does not unlock the mutex. If you want to lock a mutex, you have to wait.